# How to iterate through all pixels in a image and compare their RGB values with another RGB value without using for loop?

Tags: python, numpy

So, basically i have a array with 16 RGB color values, and i have to calculate the distance between the RGB value of a pixel in the input image and all of these 16. The RGB value which has the lower distance will be the RGB value in the output image.

The problem is: I'm using nested for loops to do these operations, and it's REALLY slow. Excerpt as follow:

```py
for i in range (row):
        for j in range (columns):
            pixel = img[i, j]
            for color in colorsarray:
                dist.append(np.linalg.norm(pixel - color))
            img[i,j] = colorsarray[dist.index(min(dist))]
            dist.clear()
```

Is there a numpy function that can help me optimize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the distances by broadcasting the arrays.

If your image has shape (x,y,3) and your palette has shape (n,3), then you can calculate the distance between each pixel and each color as an array with shape (x,y,n):

```
# distance[x,y,n] is the distance from pixel (x,y) to
# color n
distance = np.linalg.norm(
    img[:,:,None] - colors[None,None,:], axis=3)
```

The index `:` means "the entire axis" and the index `None` means "broadcast the value along this axis".

You can then choose the closest color index:

```
# pal_img[x,y] is the index of the color closest to
# pixel (x,y)
pal_img = np.argmin(distance, axis=2)
```

Finally, you can convert back to RGB:

```
# rgb_img[x,y] is the RGB color closest to pixel (x,y)
rgb_img = colors[pal_img]
```

This shows how you don't really need special functions in NumPy. Unfortunately, this can be a bit hard to understand.

Comment: well, it worked, alot faster by the way. thanks for sharing, now will try to understand what exactly happened.

Comment: @MarceloYuriBenesciutti How can you get image shape to (x,y,3) and palette shape to (n,3)?

Comment: An RGB image normally has shape (y,x,3). For example, if you get it from PIL, that's the shape it will have. If it's not (y,x,3), then it's probably not RGB and you may need to do a color space conversion first. (Note the order: Y first, and then X second.)

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you could try to vectorize your function:

```py
# reshape to have 1D array
dimx = image.shape[0]
image = image.reshape(-1, 3)

def f(pixel):
    # TODO here: logic to return, given the pixel, the closest match in the list

# vectorize the function and apply it to the image
image = np.vectorize(f)(image)

# set the shape back to original
image = image.reshape( dimx, -1, 3 )
```

Comment: please read the np.vectorize disclaimer - it does not improve speed.  Better yet do some timings yourself.